# dynamically gerDownloadURL from images on firebase storage for display

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I have a whole bunch of images that have been uploaded on firebase storage and I want to dynamically retrieve the images and display inside my app screen. This is what I tried so far without success:

I tried out the listFilesAndDirectories function found in the [RN firebase storage usage](https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage#download-urls) API reference which gives me this error:

```
 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
 Error: [storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
 NativeFirebaseError: [storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
```

```
function listFilesAndDirectories(reference, pageToken) {
  return reference.list({pageToken}).then(result => {
    // Loop over each item
    result.items.forEach(ref => {
      console.log(ref.fullPath);
    });

    if (result.nextPageToken) {
      return listFilesAndDirectories(reference, result.nextPageToken);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  });
}

const storageReference = storage()
  .ref('gs://appname445.appspot.com/images');

listFilesAndDirectories(storageReference).then(() => {
  storageReference.getDownloadURL();
  console.log('Finished listing');
});
```

the above function prints the log statement "Finished listing' but doesn't display image

I also wrote this function which didn't work, it outputs a maxDownloadRetryError after 3 minutes

```
 function fetchImage() {
   reference.getDownloadURL().then(
     function(url) {
       console.log(url);
     },
     function(error) {
       console.log(error);
     },
   );
 }

 fetchImage();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you there is no object at the location of the reference you're using.  It's not possible to use `getDownloadURL()` with a path that isn't an actul file object.  You can't use it on prefixes (folders).

If you're trying to get a download URL for each object that you listed with `listFilesAndDirectories`, you would have to call `getDownloadURL()` on **each and every file object that it finds** (not just once for the entire prefix).

It would be more like this:

```
function listFilesAndDirectories(reference, pageToken) {
  return reference.list({pageToken}).then(result => {
    result.items.forEach(ref => {
      // call getDownloadURL on every object reference
      ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        console.log(`${fullPath}: ${url}`)
      })
    });

    if (result.nextPageToken) {
      return listFilesAndDirectories(reference, result.nextPageToken);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  });
}
```

Comment: the image URLs are being logged to console, am faced with extracting the URL and placing it as a URI in an image

Comment: i have tried template literals, i tried calling the function and using the dot notaion to extract the URL but the url is not accessible outside the function scope

Comment: That sounds like a completely different problem - please post that to a new question to explain what you're dealing with now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62381079/extract-url-from-function-for-image-resource